# Python parsing out parts of a string

Tags: python, parsing

I have a string that can look like this:

Scenario 1: "some_field=(parameter_A-0-(8.869834109E-05))/(0.001*10)"

or

Scenario 2: "some_field=(parameter_A-(0.0005883943))/(0.001*10)"

How can I parse out the numbers in a decimal format as below?

Scenario 1:
First number: -0.00008869834109
Second number: 0.01

Scenario 2:
First number: 0.0005883943
Second number: 0.01

The string format stays the same but the number format and polarities can change.

Comment: You should first show what you have already tried to solve your problem and where you're stuck at.

Comment: How about using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Comment: Do you want the result to be a string, a `float` (which is a binary float and will only approximate the decimal float) or perhaps `decimal.Decimal`? And why is the first number negative and the second postive?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main work is to extract the pieces that really contain numbers from all surrounding characters. This can be done by `.split()` , `.find()`, `.rfind()` and indexing within the character strings.

My code assumes that there is exactly one equal sign '=', that the number parts are separated by '/' and each enclosed in round brackets (in the innermost if there is more than on bracket level), and there might be a sign directly left of the inner-most bracket.

```
content = "some_field=(parameter_A-0-(8.869834109E-05))/(0.001*10)"
content = "some_field=(parameter_A-(0.0005883943))/(0.001*10)"
#or which way ever you give the character strings

content = content.split('=')  #split at equal sign
if(len(content) != 2) :  #check for exactly one equal sign
  print ('something wrong in the data?') 

#in case information left of equal sign is needed
fieldname = content[0]

content = content[1]  #now work on the part which is right of '='
content = content.split('/')

values = []
for i in range(len(content)):
  x = content[i]

  pos_open  = x.rfind( '(' ) #find position of opening bracket '(', starting from right--> finds the right-most
  pos_close = x.find( ')' )
  #hence, the digits are in x[pos_open+1:pos_close]  Check this by uncommenting the following line
  #print( x[pos_open+1:pos_close]  )

  #check whether there is a multiplication included in that part
  if ( x[pos_open+1:pos_close].find('*') < 0 ) :    # .find() returns -1 if the character sequence is not found
    val = float(  x[pos_open+1:pos_close]   )    # float() does the main work of conversion 
  else:
    pos_dot = x[pos_open+1:pos_close].find('*')
    factor1 = float(  x[pos_open+1:  pos_open+1 + pos_dot]  )
    factor2 = float(  x[pos_open+1 + pos_dot+1 : pos_close] )
    val = factor1 * factor2

  #check for negative sign:  (sorry, your examples do not show clearly how the sign is specified)
  if (pos_open > 0 and x[pos_open - 1] == '-'):  # this checks the character before the bracket
    #Note: in case of pos_open=0, the second part x[pos_open - 1] would look at the LAST character x[-1]
    val = -val

  values.append(val)

#output
print ('First: {0}  Second: {1}' .format(values[0], values[1]) ) #standard way
print ('First: ' + repr(values[0]) + '  Second: ' + repr(values[1]) ) #another standard way

print ('First: {0:.12f}  Second: {1:.7f}' .format(values[0], values[1]) ) # with format specified in two exemplary ways
```

The extraction part of this code will also work if there are more than two numbers stored in the character string, as it grabs one group of characters at a time and appends the determined value `val` to the list `values`.

Comment: Thanks this works. I modified it a bit to look for the negative case, which I didn't describe clearly. Basically the '0-(8.869834109E-05)' indicates that it's negative. In the second case there is  no '0-'.